# Does npx use yarn?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, npx

Today I created a reactjs starting template with CRA using:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template redux
```

This created two files in my project: `package.json` and `yarn.lock`.

I am confused about why it worked after I `cd` in the project and ran `yarn start` even though I didn't initiate the project with `yarn create react-app my-app`.

I have two questions:

- Why it generated yarn.lock?
- What is the difference between

  - `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux` and
  - `yarn create react-app my-app --template redux` considering that they  have the same effect.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`npx create-react-app` executes `create-react-app` binary, and `create-react-app` uses `yarn` to create your project (if yarn is installed). that's why you can see `yarn.lock` and also why `yarn-start` works.

> Difference between `npx create-react-app` and `yarn create react-app`

They both executes `create-react-app` binary. `create-react-app` is the one who decides whether it wants to create the project with yarn or not. to use `npm` in `create-react-app`, use `--use-npm` flag (no matter you execute `create-react-app` with `npx` or `yarn` or `directly`, you should set it if you want it to use `npm` .):

```
create-react-app my-project --use-npm
```

Comment: `create-react-app uses yarn` explains it.

Answer (score 7):

`create-react-app` uses yarn for the setup if it's installed.

So, if yarn is already installed in your system, then `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux` and `yarn create react-app my-app --template redux` would give you the same end-result.

And it is already installed in your system, that's why it has generated yarn.lock and not package.lock.

```
yarn.lock is generated to keep the exact version of the installed packages.
```